# symfony2 user class from webservice

Tags: symfony, constructor

I am setting up a Symfony user login via a webservice.

In my UserProvider I fetch the user from the webservice(Salesforce SOAP).
Once the user is found, I create a new User object.

My problem is from the webservice the user has a lot of information I need to store.

Other than the four options provided by the cookbook - return new User($username, $password, $salt, $roles) - I need about 20 more fields with getters and setters.

What is the best way to pass these through to the User from the UserProvider without re-calling the webservice?

Am I missing something?

Any help is much appreciated.

Duncan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserProvider` must provide an instance of class which implements `UserInterface` interface. So, your `User` class can contain as many fields as you want, with condition that this class implements `UserInterface` interface.

Comment: Thanks @gatisl, from the UserProvider after I have made the call to my webservice and recieve a valid record:  
select user_bio,status,password,username from webservice where username='$username'  

return new User($username, $password, $salt, $roles)  
So how do i pass the user fields to the User object for instantiation from the record I just returned from my webservice?   There are about 20 fields returned from the webservice(ie user_bio,status)

Am I going about this incorrectly? Can I just pass them in using the constructor, that doesnt seem logical with a large number of fields.

Comment: You can use setters (but you have to define those first) of your `User` class.

`$user = new User($username, $passsword, ...);`
`$user->setStatus($status);`
`return $user;`